# GridView Not Working

Tags: gridview

I have an ASP.NET web app and want to add a GridView to display information in. I will gather the information from various database calls and add the data to a list. I want to then populate the rows in the GridView from the list.

In my html I declared a GridView like this:

In my Page_Load method, just to test, I added this:

```
if (!PostBack)
{
  GridView1.AllowPaging = true;
  GridView1.PageSize = 100;
  GridView1.ShowHeaderWhenEmpty = true;
  GridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
  GridView1.AllowSorting = true;
  GridView1.EmptyDataText = "No data to display";

  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  DataColumn[] columns =
  {
       new DataColumn("A", System.Type.GetType("System.String")),
       new DataColumn("B", System.Type.GetType("System.String")),
       new DataColumn("C", ystem.Type.GetType("System.String")),
       new DataColumn("D", System.Type.GetType("System.String")),
       new DataColumn("E", System.Type.GetType("System.String")),
       new DataColumn("F", System.Type.GetType("System.String")),
       new DataColumn("G", System.Type.GetType("System.String")),
       new DataColumn("H", System.Type.GetType("System.String")),
       new DataColumn("I", System.Type.GetType("System.String")),
       new DataColumn("J", System.Type.GetType("System.String")),
       new DataColumn("K", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
   };

            dt.Columns.AddRange(columns);
            DataRow dr;

            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = "A";
            dr[1] = "B";
            dr[2] = "C";
            dr[3] = "D";
            dr[4] = "E";
            dr[5] = "F";
            dr[6] = "G";
            dr[7] = "H";
            dr[8] = "I";
            dr[9] = "J";
            dr[10] = "K";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            GridView1.Visible = true;
}
```

This is just as test with those hard coded values. No GridView is being displayed. No errors just nothing.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is that a typo because it should be `!IsPostBack`

Comment: One suggestion. The properties of grid like pagesize, headertext etc should be set in the html itself. Setting them everytime when you are binding datasource will add up complexity.

Comment: Can you share how the grid view is declared in the html?

Answer (score 0):

I think the GridView's greatest virtue is that you do not have to write code to do some basic tasks (like viewing and modifying data). It's a good stop gap until final production code is online. A slick solution would be to use AJAX and the HtmlTable to view and change the data, but you might better off using the ListView.

Here is how you create a GridView without writing any code:
[GridView w/o code](http://www.prowaretech.com/Computer/AspNetGridView)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry I did make a type and have (!IsPostBack) in my code. As for my GridView declaration it is this:

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>

I meant to type that into my original question but forgot.